# Why is smbpasswd located in samba-client package?

Tags: linux, centos, samba, samba4

```
[root@localhost data]# yum provides smbpasswd
samba-client-4.1.12-21.el7_1.x86_64 : Samba client programs
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/smbpasswd

[root@localhost data]# yum info samba-client
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
...
Name        : samba-client
Version     : 4.1.12
Summary     : Samba client programs
...
Description : The samba4-client package provides some SMB/CIFS clients to complement
            : the built-in SMB/CIFS filesystem in Linux. These clients allow access
            : of SMB/CIFS shares and printing to SMB/CIFS printers.
```

As I understand from description of samba-client package (centos 7) it contains tools in order to connect to samba server from local host. My question - why is smbpasswd (the program that adds users to tdbsam of samba server) is located in samba-client but not samba[-server]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smbpasswd` can do several things, and one of its main purpose is to let an user change his password (even he's working on a remote client machine).

For instance, on a workstation, a client can type this to change his password:

```
smbpasswd -r pdc.mydomain.com
```

`-r` needs the PDC DNS name, and one may also use `-U` in case the SMB login name is different from the UNIX login name.

So, as you can see, `smbpasswd` is also a client tool.